# How to hide and unhide box from checkbox

Tags: java, android

I'm a student of android developer.
I need to make a project and I've ran into a problem.
basically the problem is that i need to make the box of a checkBox disappear and only after pushing a specific button, the box will appear and be clickable.
from my searches i've found that when i write:

```
myCheckBox.setButtonDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

it will disappear and it's good but couldn't find the way to make it appear after that.. 
thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that my making the view disappear either by using

```
myCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             (OR)
myCheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

And again you can make it to appear by

```
myCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope this is helpful:)

Comment: hey i want the text to be shown but not the box itself.. after clicking on a button i want the box to be shown. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
yourCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to make that visible again,

```
yourCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the currently assigned drawable with `getButtonDrawable()` and store it in a field, for example:

```
class Foo {
  private Drawable oldDrawable;
  private CheckBox myCheckBox;

  public void hideCheckbox() {
    oldDrawable = myCheckBox.getButtonDrawable();
    myCheckBox.setButtonDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
  }

  public void showCheckbox() {
    myCheckBox.setButtonDrawable(oldDrawable);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks that what i want.. but the only problem is that the drawable transparent is written in the XML of checkBox view..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. Could you try to specify? Maybe with a code example?